# Create a compareTo to a Generic Class that Implements Comparable

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable

I have a Generic Class with two type variables, which implements java.lang.Comparable.

```
public class DoubleKey<K,J> implements Comparable<DoubleKey<K,J>>{

    private K key1;
    private J key2;

    public DoubleKey(K key1, J key2){
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    } 

    public K getFirstKey(){
        return this.key1;
    }

    public J getSecondKey(){
        return this.key2;
    }

    // need for Comparable interface
    public int compareTo(DoubleKey<K,J> aThat){
        ...
    }

}
```

Becuase i implemeted it with Comparable, I need to write the compareTo() method. Because K, J can be of **ANY** type, I'm having problems on how to compare them completely. Is there a way to be able to catch all possible types (Primitive, Wrapper, Object) in the comparison? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

so to summarize the said above and to puzzle it together into a working code this is:

```
    public class DoubleKey<K extends Comparable<K>, J extends Comparable<J>>
        implements Comparable<DoubleKey<K, J>> {

    private K key1;
    private J key2;

    public DoubleKey(K key1, J key2) {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    public K getFirstKey() {
        return this.key1;
    }

    public J getSecondKey() {
        return this.key2;
    }

    public int compareTo(DoubleKey<K, J> that) {

        int cmp = this.getFirstKey().compareTo(that.getFirstKey());
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = this.getSecondKey().compareTo(that.getSecondKey());
        return cmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Would you like to introduce a requirement that `K` and `J` have a natural ordering that you can use? In this case you can declare your class `DoubleKey` like this:

```
class DoubleKey<K extends Comparable<K>, J extends Comparable<J>>
```

You can then define your DoubleKey's `compareTo` as you like. You can do things like:

```
getFirstKey().compareTo(aThat.getFirstKey())
```

You can't compare any instance of `K` to an instance of `J`, though. There is no ordering defined over those types.

If these types don't necessarily have a natural ordering (many don't), you can take a `Comparator<K>` and `Comparator<J>` as parameters to the constructor of your `DoubleKey`. A class that does this already that you can use as an example is Google Guava's excellent [Maps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) class (see specifically the `newTreeMap` methods and the bounds of the types they accept).

Comment: what does **getFirstKey().compareTo(aThat.getFirstKey())** returns when 2 variables are equal, and if not equal?

Comment: This is just the standard `Comparable` contract. In `a.compareTo(b)`, if they are equal `compareTo` returns 0, if a < b returns a negative number (usually -1), if a > b returns a positive number (usually 1).

Comment: `K extends Comparable<? super K>` would be better, because it deals with subclasses of Comparable classes appropriately

Answer (score 4):

```
public class DoubleKey<
        K implements Comparable<K>, 
        J implements Comparable<J>> 
    implements Comparable<DoubleKey<K,J>> {

    public int compareTo(DoubleKey<K,J> that){
        int cmp = this.key1.compareTo(that.key1);
        if(cmp==0) cmp = this.key2.compareTo(that.key2);
        return cmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `K extends Comparable<K>` instead of `implements`?

Comment: @Arne yes that's right. Generic type variables can only **extends**, it cannot **implement**, even if it is an interface.

Comment: *Because K, J can be of **ANY** type* - wasn't that a precondition?

Comment: `K extends Comparable<? super K>` would be better, because it deals with subclasses of Comparable classes appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define a rule *when* a `DoubleKey<K,J>` is smaller, bigger or equal to this one. That's what compare does. Maybe, that's my actual guess, it doesn't make much sense to compare to instances of `DoubleKey<K,J>`.

If you don't actual care *how* they're ordered and only need to implement *any* ordering, try this:

```
public int compareTo(DoubleKey<K,J> that){
    // real codes needs checks for null values!
    return (this.key1.toString() + this.key2.toString()).compareTo(that.key1.toString() + that.key2.toString());
}
```

Comment: But then you should make sure to document this (that `compareTo` depends on the `toString()` of the parts), and that `compareTo` is not consistent to `equals`.

Comment: It does make sence if you use for example DoubleKey<String, Animal>.  You could then use compare to compare the Object values J how you wanted depending on what fields are in them by calling their own compare methods. For example size and weight.  Alternatively, ou could compare the key strings alphabetically. It's all up to the developer of the abstract data type DoubleKey to implement behavior of their choosing and to document it well.

Answer (score 0):

First way: use hashCodes, like

```
 public int compareTo(DoubleKey<K,J> aThat){
     getFirstKey().hashCode() + getSecondKey().hashCode() - aThat.getFirstKey().hashCode() +   aThat.getSecondKey().hashCode();
 }
```

(you should think more about formula)

Second way:
add comparator to constructor

```
public DoubleKey(K key1, J key2, Comparator cmp){
```

Comment: First way is wrong, because "_[It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())_", also the `int` in hashCode is arbitrary, you can't assume that an `Object` with hachCode 42 is greater than an `Object` with hashCode 1.

Comment: @Electro, Of course it's bad way. But, there isn't any criteria for comparing Object, so you can use Ordering by hashCodes)

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, there exists a library that can solve your problem: [Apache Commons lang3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). I often use [Pair<L,R>](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) instances as keys. They implement Comparable.