# Java Error passing an argument to a method that takes T where T extends Comparable<T>

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class declaration:

```
public class UserVariable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<UserVariable<T>>
{
    private T myValue;

    public void setValue(T value)
    {
        myValue = value;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        return myValue;
    }

    public int compareTo(UserVariable<T> rhs)
    {
        return getValue().compareTo(rhs.getValue());

    }
}
```

If I did that correctly, what I wanted is: `UserVariable` can be compared to other `UserVariable`s and it's generic and accepts a type `T` that can be compared to other `T`s.

I am having trouble invoking `setValue()` and passing it an Integer:

```
UserVariable<Integer> newVar = new UserVariable<Integer>();
newVar.setValue(new Integer(20));
```

gives me the error "The method `setValue(Comparable<Comparable<T>>)` in the type `UserVariable<Comparable<Comparable<T>>>` is not applicable for the arguments (`Integer`)".

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  First, `Integer` does implement `Comparable<Integer>`.  Second, why does `Comparable` appear twice, in a nested fashion (`Comparable<Comparable<T>>`) in the error message?  Yes, `UserVariable` also implements `Comparable` but the error is referring to the type of the method parameter, which is of type `T`, which should just be a `T extends Comparable<T>`, right?

UPDATE:

I've realized the problem is connected with the fact that I am retrieving the object from a wildcard collection:

```
Map<String, UserVariable<?>> myVars = new HashMap<>();

UserVariable<Double> v1 = new UserVariable<>();
v1.setValue(3.0);

myVars.put("doubleVar", v1);

myVars.get("doubleVar").setValue(new Double(30));
```

Adding the above code will reproduce the compile error on the last line.

My apologies, I'm afraid the question scope has changed entirely with that latest info, because I am pulling an object from the map of type `UserVariable<?>` and trying to call `setValue()` on that.

Comment: You should use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, however seeing that `Integer` implments `Comparable<Integer>` and not `Comparable<Number>` this is unlikely the source of your problem.

Comment: `public setValue` should be `public void setValue`. otherwise, after implementing compareTo, I can call `setValue(new Integer(20))` without an error

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013947/create-a-compareto-to-a-generic-class-that-implements-comparable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544716/implementing-comparable-with-a-generic-class

Comment: setValue must be void , you wrote it like a constructor ...

Comment: `UserVariable` doesn't implement `CompareTo()`, `public setValue()` has no returned type.  How this code can compile ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  When I typed my question I left out the `void`.  Oops, sorry.  It does exist in my code.  The error is still the same.

Comment: I will add the compareTo() function.  I left it out because right now it just returns 0.  But I'll add it for clarity.

Comment: what version of javac are you using? It compiles and runs for me fine after fixing the void and compareTo. Java 8 here.

Comment: I think all I needed was to cast the object to a `UserVariable<Double>` in the last line: `(UserVariable<Double>)(myVars.get("doubleVar")).setValue(new Double(30));`  I get an unchecked cast warning, for good reason, but this is an issue with the wildcard in the Map and not an issue with the class declaration after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that need changing:

- `public class UserVariable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<UserVariable<T>>`

  In class declaration, you are implementing `Comparable<UserVariable<T>>` where `UserVariable` itself again implements `Comparable` that's why you are getting `Comparable<Comparable<T>>` in the error message.
- `public setValue(T value)`

  Don't know whether it's a typo but the method needs a return type, you can   change it to `public void setValue(T value)`

Below is an example that works after making these changes:

```
public class UserVariable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<T> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private T myValue;

    public void setValue(T value){
        myValue = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserVariable<Integer> newVar = new UserVariable<Integer>();
        newVar.setValue(new Integer(20));
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you want to compare two `UserVariable` objects the you just need to implement `compareTo` method and add `return type` to setter method, below should work:

```
public class UserVariable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<UserVariable<T>> {
    private T myValue;

    public void setValue(T value) {
        myValue = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return myValue;
    }

    public int compareTo(UserVariable<T> rhs) {
        return getValue().compareTo(rhs.getValue());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserVariable<Integer> newVar = new UserVariable<Integer>();
        newVar.setValue(new Integer(20));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I would like to be able to compare `UserVariable<T>` to another `UserVariable<T>`, rather than comparing it to a `T`

Comment: @skrilmps I have updated my answer and added another example for `UserVariable<T>`.